# How to timeout a statement

Tags: python, python-2.7, jython, wlst

how to time-out a statement/block of code in python?

I tried using the below looking at a post but it couldn't identify the signal:

```
wls:/offline> import signal

Traceback (innermost last):

  File "<console>", line 1, in ?

ImportError: no module named signal
```

code:

```
import os
import signal

def handler(signum, frame):
    print "Forever is over!"    
    raise Exception("end of time")

def loop_forever():
    import time
    while 1:
        print "sec"
        time.sleep(1)

signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
signal.alarm(10)

try:
    loop_forever()
except Exception, exc:
    print exc
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be more easily done with threads?

Comment: what OS are you running this on ? The above should work on a `UNIX` based system

Comment: @RiccardoCagnasso not necessarily, threads are not always the best choice in python. And that snippet is pretty *easily done* to me ;-)

Comment: One thing I observed is if I run it as python script its working.If I run it using java/WLST its not identifying signal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be working

Which calls a method after the timeout:

```
from threading import Timer

import time


def timeout():

    print 'in timeout'


def main():

    print 'it keeps going and going ',

    while 1:

        print 'and going '

        time.sleep(3)


try:

    Timer(5.0,timeout).start()

    main()

except:

    print "whoops"
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code is working perfectly well for me:

```
>>> import os
>>> import signal
>>> 
>>> def handler(signum, frame):
...     print "Forever is over!"    
...     raise Exception("end of time")
... 
>>> def loop_forever():
...     import time
...     while 1:
...         print "sec"
...         time.sleep(1)
... 
>>> signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
0
>>> signal.alarm(10)
0
>>> 
>>> try:
...     loop_forever()
... except Exception, exc:
...     print exc
... 
sec
sec
sec
sec
sec
sec
sec
sec
sec
sec
Forever is over!
end of time
```

Though, are you using a Unix system to try this? Whether this is a Linux, a BSD or a Mac? The signal module may not be present at all on other OS, as this is using a feature very specific to unix systems, even though windows does have a very basic support of POSIX processes.

edit: Well, as I'm saying you're in a very particular case, which is neither Unix or windows or even symbian ; but you're running it in Jython, which does not have access to the OS features, whereas the lack of `signal` module. You should have tagged your question with Jython, to help us help you more efficiently! Then you'd better use a thread timer which should be well implemented in Jython.

As a very basic example:

```
 >>> threading.Timer(5.0, lambda: print("toto")).start()
```

As a more complex example, where I'm using a simple lock semaphore to handle
the signaling between the main thread and the timer thread:

```
>>> import time
>>> import threading
>>> l = threading.Lock()
>>> threading.Timer(5.0, lambda l: l.acquire(), args=(l,)).start()
>>> while not l.locked():
...   print("sec")
...   time.sleep(1)
... 
sec
sec
sec
sec
sec
>>>
```

Comment: ``signal`` as a module is available on Windows, it's just limited to a very small subset of possible signals. The doc specifies which are available on the platfrom

Comment: that's why I used the modal `may` and added "*even though windows does have a very basic support of POSIX processes*". ;-)

Comment: One thing I observed is if I run it as python script its working.If I run it using java/WLST its not identifying signal

Comment: well, as I'm saying you're in a very particular case, which is neither Unix or windows, but you're running it in Jython, which does not have access to the OS features, whereas the lack of `signal` module. Then you'd better use a thread timer which should be well implemented in Jython.

Comment: @zmo Indeed, that was my point. ``signal`` should be available on Windows, so it wouldn't have explained the ``ImportError``. But if Jython can't pass signals, and thus doesn't implement the ``signal`` module, that would.

Comment: Although the [documentation](http://www.jython.org/docs/library/signal.html) says that it should be there.

Comment: yup, but who knows about the WSTL particular context? Anyway, however `signal` is present or not on Jython, `signal.alarm` is specific to Unix systems and won't be avaible. So the OP has anyway to use another solution.

Comment: its running the loop until 5 seconds. How to I execute only once. Say I am connecting to database, dont want to connect again within 5 seconds